# apache fails to load mod_wsgi: complains of 'missing symbol'

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi

When I run `apachectl configtest` after installing mod_wsgi I get the following error message:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 117 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so, 10): Symbol not found: _PyEval_ReleaseLock\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so\n  Expected in: dynamic lookup\n`

I compiled mod_wsgi 3.5 from source with python 2.7.8. Apache is version 2.2.11. Extensive googling turned up no similar problems. It's possible that apache is trying to use the system version of python rather than the one I have installed (also the one I used to compile mod_wsgi).

Any ideas what is causing this error and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling Apache and other modules or applications that Apache will depend on and they are in a different location than the system wide LD confgiuration, then your startup script should probably specify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Example from one of my own servers that has a lot of custom compiled code:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/apache/lib:/opt/zlib/lib:/opt/openssl/lib";export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can also use "ldd" against any of the modules to see what dynamic libraries it is referencing.  If your various compiler flags or options were missing includes to the right locations, you may have a mix of the wrong heads and libraries.  This can lead to even more confusing behavior because an application may start, but then segfault under certain conditions.